# Laravel _ How to inject a query into Auth::user()

Tags: php, laravel

I'm making a blog with laravel. When I look into user authentication, I have a few issues here. I have 2 tables, one is users: id, name, ... the other is role: user_id, privilege .. I need to check whether a user is admin or not, I will need a function like `isAdmin()` or a `$isAdmin` attribute. This is my function placed in the **app/providers/AuthServiceProvider.php**:

```
private static $isAdmin;

public static function isAdmin() {
    if (isset(self::$isAdmin)) {
        return self::$isAdmin;
    }
    $user_privilege = DB::table('role')
        ->select('privilege')
        ->where([
            ['privilege', '=', 'admin'],
            ['user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id],
        ])
        ->get()
        ->first();
    self::$isAdmin = isset($user_privilege->privilege);
    return self::$isAdmin;
}
```

This code works fine, but this will require two queries to the database to check the user's admin rights. So I wanted to find a way to inject a query into Auth :: user () so that only one query would retrieve all the stuff I wanted. I'm a beginner with laravel. Can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that user can have only one role. You can create `isAdmin()` method in the `User` model:

```
public function isAdmin()
{
    return auth()->user()->role->privilege === 'admin';
}
```

Define the relationship if you didn't do that yet:

```
public function role()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Role::class);
}
```

Then use it with `auth()->user()->isAdmin()`.

If a user can have many roles:

```
public function isAdmin()
{
    auth()->user()->loadMissing('roles');
    return auth()->user()->roles->contains('admin');
}
```

And the relationship:

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Role::class);
}
```

Comment: @imdev please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) if you're going to use this code.

Comment: @imdev Alexey's image is off slightly, the checkbox is [here](https://imgur.com/a/PkwYY)

Comment: @btl well, your code will not work and will throw `BadMethodCallException` because Laravel doesn't have `hasRole()` method.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I'm just messing with you. Your answer is clearly usable as opposed to mine as it is.

Answer (score 2):

On your User model define an `isAdmin` method:

```
public function isAdmin() {
    // simplified your query here
    return $this->hasRole('admin');
}
```

Then it will be accessible on the Auth guard like:

```
Auth::user()->isAdmin();
```